# Composable view does not recompose when coming back from background

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have my composable which I am displaying the content according to some states. First time I open the screen everything works fine but when I move my app to background and then come back it stops being recomposed. When I try to debug it I can see that the state is changing but for some reason my view is not being updated. Here is my composable:

```
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    val isKeyboardOpen by keyboardAsState()
    var buttonHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .imePadding()
            .verticalScroll(scrollState)
            .background(color = White),
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(
                start = 18.dp,
                end = 18.dp,
                top = 22.dp,
                bottom = 12.dp
            ),
            text = "text",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1,
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface
        )
        BasicTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = 18.dp)
                .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                    if (isKeyboardOpen == Keyboard.Opened) {
                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            scrollState.animateScrollTo(coordinates.positionInParent().y.roundToInt())
                        }
                    }
                },
            onValueChange = { onEvent.invoke(Event.ReasonFieldValueChanged(it)) },
            onFocused = { onEvent.invoke(Event.ReasonFieldFocused) }
        )
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 10.dp, vertical = 24.dp),
            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.background,
            elevation = 0.dp
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
                text = "text",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1.secondary
            )
        }

        if (isKeyboardOpen == Keyboard.Closed) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            CloseAccountButton(state, onEvent, isKeyboardOpen) {
                buttonHeight = it
            }
        } else {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(buttonHeight))
        }
    }
    if (isKeyboardOpen == Keyboard.Opened) {
        CloseAccountButton(state, onEvent, isKeyboardOpen) {
            buttonHeight = it
        }
    }
```

And here is how I get keyboard state:

```
enum class Keyboard {
    Opened, Closed
}

@Composable
fun keyboardAsState(): State<Keyboard> {
    val keyboardState = remember { mutableStateOf(Keyboard.Closed) }
    val view = LocalView.current
    DisposableEffect(view) {
        val onGlobalListener = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            val rect = Rect()
            view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect)
            val screenHeight = view.rootView.height
            val keypadHeight = screenHeight - rect.bottom
            keyboardState.value = if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) {
                Keyboard.Opened
            } else {
                Keyboard.Closed
            }
        }
        view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalListener)

        onDispose {
            view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalListener)
        }
    }

    return keyboardState
}
```

As I said on first opening of the screen everything is fine but when coming back from background neither scrolling to position nor raacting to keyboard visibility is working. I don't have much experience with compose, what is wrong here?